# Use model input to amend SQL Query in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-modeler

Is there a way I can use a model input in QGIS modeler to amend the parameters of a SQL query.

For example I want a model input (string) to allow me to pick the name of someone I am searching for in a database. In the example below the name is 'Tim'

[image]

I know I can change between a 'value', 'pre calculated value', 'model input' and 'algorithm output' but none of these seem to allow me to change a specific parameter within the script.